# Typeahead shows not all items from json

Tags: javascript, json, typeahead.js

So, I have working twitter typeahead.js script, but noticed, that sometimes(with some keywords) it shows not all results from json:

One of the case:
Where is 3 objects in this received json, but search form returns only first one:

```
[
{
"query":"David Flanagan - JavaScript",
"id":"7",
"image":"\u003Cimg src=\u0022http:\/\/bks5.books.google.lt\/books\/content?id=4RChxt67lvwC\u0026printsec=frontcover\u0026img=1\u0026zoom=1\u0026edge=curl\u0026source=gbs_api\u0022\u003E"
},
{
"query":"Stoyan Stefanov - JavaScript Patterns",
"id":"10",
"image":"\u003Cimg src=\u0022http:\/\/bks8.books.google.lt\/books\/content?id=ZEmbAgAAQBAJ\u0026printsec=frontcover\u0026img=1\u0026zoom=1\u0026source=gbs_api\u0022\u003E"
},
{
"query":"Douglas Crockford - JavaScript: The Good Parts",
"id":"9",
"image":"\u003Cimg src=\u0022http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/518QVtPWA7L._SL160_.jpg\u0022\u003E"
}
]
```

search form result:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/PjLOrFt.png]

my typeahead script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var books = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '/search/auto/?q=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY',
        }
    });

    $('#books_search').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 3,
            limit: 5
        },
        {
            name: 'book-search',
            display: 'query',
            source: books,
            templates: {
                empty: [
                    '<div class="empty-message">Unable to find any books that match the current query</div>'
                ]
            }
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function(e, data) {
            $("#search-form").submit();
        });
});
```

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: did u try using this datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("query"),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was typeahead.js bug, here is solution: (it's committed, but not in master yet):

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/1200

Answer (score 0):

Did u try using this 
`datumTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("query");`
(I used local data instead of remote but both works same way)
here is the demo-link which works fine 
http://jsfiddle.net/7q3xk10y/